# How to create dynamically a simple json array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I know this questions exists like 100 times, but I just can't transfer the solutions to my code, so I hope you can help me. This should be pretty easy but I just don't get it working.

This is just my code with other variable because of reasons:

My Code:

```
for (var key in array) {
}
```

The JSON I want:

```
[{
    key: "One",
    y: 5
}, {
    key: "Two",
    y: 2
},];
```

Pseudo JSON:

```
[{
    key: key,
    y: array[key].data
},{
    key: key,
    y: array[key].data;
},];
```

Comment: Is `array` an object or an array?

Comment: Array is a list or an object?

Comment: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Note that nothing about this is anything to do with JSON - it's just plain old arrays and objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
var data = [];
for (var key in array) {
  data.push({
    key :  key,
    y : array[key].data
  });
}

console.log(data);
```

But, what about `Pseudo JSON:`?

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/3pL9hkyx/) - *See console (chrome) for output*

Comment: Thanks a lot that is perfectly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what is 'array'. Is it an object or an array?

I think what you want might be this, if 'array' is an array:

```
var new_arr = [];

your_array.forEach( function(entry) {
  new_arr.push({key: entry, y: entry.data}); // you should change it according to your need. 
})

return JSON.stringify(new_arr);
```

Or if 'array' is just an object, you may need this:

```
var new_arr = [];

for (key in array) {
  new_arr.push({key: key, y: array[key].data}); // you should change it according to your need. 
}

return JSON.stringify(new_arr);
```

Comment: @Yoshi foolish me... don't use 'new', use another word.

Comment: @Yoshi yea... I've edited it. Thank you for point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is just a syntax for expressing objects and arrays independently of a scripting language's syntax.
Apparently you want to convert your `array` into another structure and have this expressed in JSON. The conversion to JSON is usually performed by the built-in function [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Assuming your `array` isn't really an array (which has only numeric indices, usually without gaps), but more an object-like structure, I'd suggest the following code:

```
var data = []
for (var key in array)
{
    data.push({key: key, y: array[key].data});
}
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
//...
```

If `array` really was an array [you shouldn't use a for-in-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). Otherwise you should consider renaming it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following line to create an array of json

```
var jsonArr = [];
```

then you can create json object from following line

```
var obj = new Object();
```

put data in json object as following

```
obj['id'] = 123;
obj['name'] = 'ABC';
```

then put json object in json array as

```
jsonArr.push(obj);
```

you want to add multiple objects in json array then simply create json object and add one by one using `push` method.

```
[{"id":"123","name":"ABC"}]
```